# need help understanding pytorch blitz math notation

Tags: pytorch

I just came across this notation in the [pytorch blitz tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-blitz-autograd-tutorial-py) and I dont know what the vertical line is

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions on the notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical line means the value of the left side variable given that the right side variable is a particular value. So, your given example means `z_i` is 27 when `x_i` is 1.

Basically, it means 'LHS holds given RHS'